# How do I get my project onto a Cloud Server? Capistrano, Filezilla ..?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, digital-ocean, filezilla

I'm so confused on how I get my application onto my DigitalOcean cloud server. I've spent a solid day and a half trying to figure this out. Without the necessary background knowledge, I'm so lost. Do I use Filezilla? I tried that and it moved the files successfully but I couldnt get it to start.

I looked into Capistrano 3 tutorials but it seems like the application file is already uploaded to the cloud server.

I'm aware there is an option to push from Github, perhaps?

Can anyone help clarify what the steps are for me to deploy? This is all so confusing!

Comment: I'd try Heroku. It's more expensive, but there's less to learn. (And it has a free tier anyway)

Comment: I already bought the droplet on digitalocean, but ill give heroku a try since its got a free option.